# how to login into the database with username, password using python code?

Tags: python, pymongo

I have two mongodb database(Admin, dadus). In one database, i have stored database details like database name, username and password.

```
use Admin
db.org.insert({database : "dadus", uid : "dadus_user", pwd : "dadus_user"})
```

now we will use the above databasename, username and password details login into the dadus database using Python code.

My python code below:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
cleint = MonogoClient(port = 27017)
db = client.Admin
col = db.org
CORS(app)

@app.route('/users/login', methods=['POST'])
def login:
connection = col.find_one({"database" : "dadus"})
```

after find the database details in JSON format, how to login into the dadus database using python?

Answer (score 0):

You can login to like this:

```
new_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://{}:{}@localhost/dadus".format(connection.uid,connection.pwd))
```

Comment: when i execute the above query, i get some error like   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'uid'

Comment: Try `connection['uid']`

Comment: Can you share `connection` value? You need to add handling for None values.

Comment: Thanks for your support. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54131806/10297042 please open the link, i have explained clearly, what i need.